# Two buttons next to eachother, with a span in between

Tags: html, forms, css

I'm trying to get two `<button>`s side-by-side, so that there's an absolutely positioned(?) label in between of them.

See ASCII art for clarification

`_________Click_either_________
|___BTN1_____|O R|______BTN2__|`

The BTNs both need to have `width:50%`, so the OR label needs to be absolutely positioned, as far as I can tell, otherwise it won't fit.
The problem is that I have no idea how to center the label, without defining height and width for it. I want it to shrink to the size of it's content. To clarify, the label needs to be centered both vertically and horizontally.

There is no defined height for any of the elements.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5awNx/1/

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net of what you have tried so far

Comment: Consider using flexbox.

Comment: which is the span text in your ASCII art? the `click either` or the `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` to position the buttons and `position: absolute;` to position the hint. I also added some more semantic html (actually it is not really good). Have a look at this fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/m2X5f/

**EDIT:** Here is an updated version with a vertically centered hint as well (But only with a fixed height): http://jsfiddle.net/m2X5f/2/

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't vertically center the label. See http://jsfiddle.net/m2X5f/1/

Comment: Oh. Did not know, it should be vertically centered, too.

Comment: @Lubrikitten I added a new version. Thanks.

Comment: The site's completely fluid, which means that I can't have `px` dimensions. And a `%` height won't work because as I said, none of the elements have a height defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this :
[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/64G96/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="b1"><button>Left Button</button></td>
        <td id="txt">Hello</td>
        <td id="b2"><button>Right Button</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `#txt`would need to be **on top** of the buttons, not next to them.

Answer (score 0):

this is an update to your JSFiddle (using CSS3): [**http://jsfiddle.net/5awNx/4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/5awNx/3/)

```
#label
{
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);

}
```